# How do I match coordinates (longitude/latitude) to census blocks?

Tags: r, polygon, latitude-longitude, census

I have a set of longitude/latitude coordinates in a .csv file and need to match them to their census blocks. I've been trying to figure out how to do this in R using the UScensus2010 package, which includes SpacialPolygonDataFrames for each state and polygons for each block group. How can a match these coordinates to their block group?

This is what the first item in the polygon list (from UScensus2010@polygons) looks like:

```
An object of class "Polygons"
Slot "Polygons":
[[1]]
An object of class "Polygon"
Slot "labpt":
[1] -75.88144  42.18167

Slot "area":
[1] 0.0006202178

Slot "hole":
[1] FALSE

Slot "ringDir":
[1] 1

Slot "coords":
            [,1]     [,2]
  [1,] -75.87509 42.17416
  [2,] -75.87541 42.17414
  [3,] -75.87557 42.17413
  [4,] -75.87571 42.17411
  [5,] -75.87599 42.17410
  [6,] -75.87901 42.17396
  [7,] -75.87904 42.17396
  [8,] -75.87908 42.17396
  [9,] -75.87931 42.17393
 [10,] -75.87936 42.17391
 [11,] -75.87943 42.17385
 [12,] -75.87967 42.17345
 [13,] -75.87982 42.17323
 [14,] -75.87992 42.17311
 [15,] -75.88004 42.17301
 [16,] -75.88055 42.17269
 [17,] -75.88072 42.17257
 [18,] -75.88076 42.17253
 [19,] -75.88080 42.17244
 [20,] -75.88080 42.17229
 [21,] -75.88068 42.17182
 [22,] -75.88067 42.17166
 [23,] -75.88069 42.17054
 [24,] -75.88070 42.17043
 [25,] -75.88074 42.16901
 [26,] -75.88191 42.16884
 [27,] -75.88257 42.16875
 [28,] -75.88325 42.16864
 [29,] -75.88486 42.16844
 [30,] -75.88521 42.16840
 [31,] -75.88658 42.16828
 [32,] -75.88702 42.16825
 [33,] -75.88735 42.16826
 [34,] -75.88771 42.16829
 [35,] -75.88820 42.16770
 [36,] -75.88829 42.16759
 [37,] -75.88836 42.16751
 [38,] -75.88851 42.16734
 [39,] -75.88938 42.16631
 [40,] -75.89001 42.16561
 [41,] -75.89125 42.16422
 [42,] -75.89165 42.16374
 [43,] -75.89213 42.16320
 [44,] -75.89258 42.16272
 [45,] -75.89341 42.16183
 [46,] -75.89346 42.16187
 [47,] -75.89359 42.16200
 [48,] -75.89417 42.16270
 [49,] -75.89444 42.16301
 [50,] -75.89500 42.16362
 [51,] -75.89553 42.16421
 [52,] -75.89596 42.16467
 [53,] -75.89563 42.16609
 [54,] -75.89556 42.16651
 [55,] -75.89554 42.16687
 [56,] -75.89554 42.16712
 [57,] -75.89557 42.16749
 [58,] -75.89565 42.16790
 [59,] -75.89575 42.16825
 [60,] -75.89589 42.16870
 [61,] -75.89668 42.17135
 [62,] -75.89760 42.17439
 [63,] -75.89804 42.17560
 [64,] -75.89829 42.17622
 [65,] -75.89876 42.17728
 [66,] -75.89920 42.17815
 [67,] -75.89054 42.18697
 [68,] -75.88629 42.19130
 [69,] -75.88553 42.19212
 [70,] -75.88494 42.19192
 [71,] -75.88338 42.19143
 [72,] -75.88261 42.19109
 [73,] -75.88189 42.19073
 [74,] -75.88129 42.19045
 [75,] -75.88115 42.19065
 [76,] -75.88096 42.19090
 [77,] -75.88072 42.19114
 [78,] -75.88047 42.19138
 [79,] -75.88008 42.19170
 [80,] -75.87972 42.19196
 [81,] -75.87933 42.19220
 [82,] -75.87908 42.19234
 [83,] -75.87851 42.19260
 [84,] -75.87817 42.19274
 [85,] -75.87760 42.19294
 [86,] -75.87643 42.19337
 [87,] -75.87628 42.19342
 [88,] -75.87543 42.19373
 [89,] -75.87508 42.19385
 [90,] -75.87479 42.19393
 [91,] -75.87369 42.19421
 [92,] -75.87233 42.19446
 [93,] -75.87187 42.19455
 [94,] -75.87097 42.19469
 [95,] -75.87037 42.19479
 [96,] -75.86948 42.19496
 [97,] -75.86923 42.19501
 [98,] -75.86776 42.19532
 [99,] -75.86678 42.19553
[100,] -75.86646 42.19560
[101,] -75.86503 42.19596
[102,] -75.86470 42.19606
[103,] -75.86430 42.19622
[104,] -75.86394 42.19638
[105,] -75.86367 42.19651
[106,] -75.86304 42.19687
[107,] -75.86249 42.19724
[108,] -75.86233 42.19736
[109,] -75.86212 42.19750
[110,] -75.86158 42.19798
[111,] -75.86113 42.19841
[112,] -75.86102 42.19834
[113,] -75.86071 42.19819
[114,] -75.86050 42.19810
[115,] -75.86027 42.19803
[116,] -75.85999 42.19798
[117,] -75.85977 42.19795
[118,] -75.85943 42.19794
[119,] -75.85929 42.19795
[120,] -75.85930 42.19778
[121,] -75.85937 42.19716
[122,] -75.85944 42.19657
[123,] -75.85947 42.19627
[124,] -75.85949 42.19608
[125,] -75.85948 42.19553
[126,] -75.85940 42.19456
[127,] -75.85940 42.19450
[128,] -75.85919 42.19215
[129,] -75.85919 42.19182
[130,] -75.85924 42.19156
[131,] -75.85935 42.19128
[132,] -75.85946 42.19107
[133,] -75.85966 42.19081
[134,] -75.86037 42.19004
[135,] -75.86068 42.18970
[136,] -75.86084 42.18952
[137,] -75.86113 42.18923
[138,] -75.86124 42.18913
[139,] -75.86276 42.18880
[140,] -75.86330 42.18865
[141,] -75.86357 42.18856
[142,] -75.86388 42.18846
[143,] -75.86459 42.18819
[144,] -75.86523 42.18789
[145,] -75.86569 42.18765
[146,] -75.86641 42.18722
[147,] -75.86680 42.18696
[148,] -75.86705 42.18677
[149,] -75.86738 42.18649
[150,] -75.86861 42.18532
[151,] -75.86902 42.18492
[152,] -75.86918 42.18475
[153,] -75.86982 42.18409
[154,] -75.87090 42.18285
[155,] -75.87295 42.18047
[156,] -75.87327 42.18006
[157,] -75.87352 42.17969
[158,] -75.87357 42.17961
[159,] -75.87372 42.17937
[160,] -75.87398 42.17887
[161,] -75.87414 42.17847
[162,] -75.87419 42.17836
[163,] -75.87433 42.17795
[164,] -75.87444 42.17752
[165,] -75.87453 42.17703
[166,] -75.87484 42.17417
[167,] -75.87504 42.17416
[168,] -75.87509 42.17416



Slot "plotOrder":
[1] 1

Slot "labpt":
[1] -75.88144  42.18167

Slot "ID":
[1] "new_york.blkgrp10_1"

Slot "area":
[1] 0.0006202178
```

I think the over() or point.in.SpatialPolygon functions make the most sense but I can't figure out how to use them. I created a SpatialPoints object with test coordinates:

```
dat <- data.frame(Longitude = -73.92642301, Latitude = 40.63296731)
coordinates(dat) <- ~ Longitude + Latitude
```

Then, I try to use over() to pick out the census block group:

```
over(dat, new_york.blkgrp10@polygons)
```

Which gives the error message:

```
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘over’ for signature ‘"SpatialPoints", "list"’
```

How can I fix this and/or is there an easier way to assign census block groups to longitude/latitude coordinates?

Comment: you don't need the `@polygons` in the `over` call

Comment: When I run `over(dat, new_york.blkgrp10)` it gives the error message `Error: identicalCRS(x, y) is not TRUE`. Am I coding the long-lat point wrong?